# How to set the default for links to open in a new window in NicEdit

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, nicedit

When using NicEdit, text can be highlighted such that it can be hyperlinked, using the 'Add Link' button in the editor.

When clicking the 'Add Link' button, a popup appears where you can specify whether the link should open in a new window, or in the current window. This defaults to 'Current Window'.

I assumed that switching the order of these two options around in the javascript in line 72 would change the default from 'Current Window' to 'New Window'. But, this is not the case.

How to set the default for added links, using NicEdit, to open in a new window, instead of the current window?

Here's the relevant bit of code from the NicEdit javascript.

```
var nicLinkOptions = {
buttons : {
    'link' : {name : 'Add Link', type : 'nicLinkButton', tags : ['A']},
    'unlink' : {name : 'Remove Link',  command : 'unlink', noActive : true}
}
```

};

```
var nicLinkButton=nicEditorAdvancedButton.extend({addPane:function(){this.ln=this.ne.selectedInstance.selElm().parentTag("A");this.addForm({"":{type:"title",txt:"Add/Edit Link"},href:{type:"text",txt:"URL",value:"http://",style:{width:"150px"}},title:{type:"text",txt:"Title"},target:{type:"select",txt:"Open In",options:{_blank:"New Window","":"Current Window"},style:{width:"100px"}}},this.ln)},submit:function(C){var A=this.inputs.href.value;if(A=="http://"||A==""){alert("You must enter a URL to Create a Link");return false}this.removePane();if(!this.ln){var B="javascript:nicTemp();";this.ne.nicCommand("createlink",B);this.ln=this.findElm("A","href",B)}if(this.ln){this.ln.setAttributes({href:this.inputs.href.value,title:this.inputs.title.value,target:this.inputs.target.options[this.inputs.target.selectedIndex].value})}}});nicEditors.registerPlugin(nicPlugin,nicLinkOptions);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change order is the right way, but use '_self' for the "Current Window", that works for me.

And have an eye on double or single quotes

Comment: So simple, yet so effective.